# Функция setprecision c/c++ Особенности компиляторов

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, компилятор

Написал вот такой код на visual-studio-2017:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <clocale>
#include <string>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    cout << "============================================== " << endl
    << "Введите 6 строк массива А. Каждая строка состоит из 4 вещественных чисел, разделенных пробелом." << endl
    << "Ожидание ввода..." << endl;



const int M = 6, N=4;
char A[1000];
double dA[M][N]{};

for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    gets_s(A);
    char *strnum = strtok(A, " ");
    int j = 0; 
    while (strnum != NULL)
    {
        dA[i][j] = atof(strnum);
        j++;
        strnum = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

}
for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
    cout << setprecision(2) << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << dA[m][n] << '\t';

    }

return 0;
}
```

Все работает корректно на Visual studio. Однако при переносе в другую среду разработки и использовании компилятора MinGW на консоль и в файл выводятся числа без дробной части. Вот код для MinGW:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
cout

    << "Введите 6 строк массива А. Каждая строка состоит из 4 вещественных чисел, разделенных пробелом." << endl
    << "Ожидание ввода..." << endl;



const int M = 6, N=4;
char A[1000];
double dA[M][N]{};

for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    gets(A);
    char *strnum = strtok(A, " ");
    int j = 0; 
    while (strnum != NULL)
    {
        dA[i][j] = atof(strnum);
        j++;
        strnum = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

}
cout << endl;
for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
    cout << setprecision(2) << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << dA[m][n] << '\t';

    }
return 0;
}
```

При вводе матрицы, к примеру:

```
"1,01 1,2 4,5 4,1"
"1,7 1,1 1,1 0,01"
"1,7 1,1 1,1 0,01"
"1,7 1,1 1,1 0,01"
"1,7 1,1 1,1 0,01"
"1,7 1,1 1,1 0,01"
```

MinGW выводит:

```
  1.00 1.00 4.00 4.00
  1.00 1.00 1.00 0.00
  1.00 1.00 1.00 0.00
  1.00 1.00 1.00 0.00
  1.00 1.00 1.00 0.00
  1.00 1.00 1.00 0.00
```

Как это исправить? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Сократите пример до минимального...

Comment: @VTT не понял Вас. Проблема в том, что Visual studio переводит все корректно, а MinGW отбрасывают целую часть. Для ввода использую setpresicion. Надеюсь, вопрос теперь понятен, спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос-то понятен, но приведенный код неимоверно длинный для иллюстрации такой проблемы, так что радикально подсократите его. Ввод, расчеты и матрицы к вопросу не имеют никакого отношения.

Comment: @VTT Все сократил.  И все-таки, как исправить проблему?

Comment: А зачем вы вообще читаете строку, да ещё и gets, потом парсите её, почему нельзя просто через cin считать? скорей всего тут проблема и кроется

Comment: @BeaverFeller Задание такое весёлое, ввести матрицу строками, а работать с числами.

Comment: Скорей всего вы что-то неправильно поняли, ввод что для строк, что для чисел одинаковый, всегда вводятся символы(имею ввиду через консоль), а уже представление данных в программе зависит от того как мы их интерпретируем. Сделайте нормальный ввод через cin или хотя бы переделайте свой парсер на string и функции  c++

Comment: @BeaverFeller Цитата из задания: "...Ввод нужно осуществлять с помощью строковой переменной. Ввод организовать таким образом, чтобы вводилась строка матрицы за один раз целиком. Разделение цифр в строке осуществляйте с помощью пробелов. Дальше следует выделить из введенной строки отдельные строки, содержащие числа и осуществить преобразование полученных строк в числовые значения. ,,," Вопрос-то не в этом, а в том почему MinGW не хочет работать корректно, хотя Visual Studio работает

Comment: ставлю на то, что вы прочитали целое число из-за различий запятой и точки. Сократите пример до минимального. [mcve]

Comment: @pavel Спасибо. В MinGW нужно вводить данные с точкой и все заработает, а в visual studio — с запятой. Я так понял это связано со strtok и разным использованием локали в разных компиляторах.

Comment: Со strtok это не связано. Это связано с atof.